# Way to find out allocation type of variables in function

Tags: c++, c, optimization, gcc, g++

I want to find out storage type of variables in a function block. How to check if compiler has elevated auto variable storage to register storage or if variables declared with register storage are honored by compiler? I am assuming by seeing the assembly code of the obj file after optimization would give us an idea. Please list the switch that I need to use with gcc or cl.exe to get this information?

Comment: Yo're assuming that auto vs register is a boolean choice. Modern compilers can decide on an instruction-by-instruction basis which variables are in registers; it may change literally in the middle of a line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-S` switch in gcc is the one you are looking for.
See [§3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output (GCC manual)](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html)

Comment: this should be working: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options

Comment: @Tobias: Link fixed. (I accidentally deleted the l from the end of it. Sorry)

Comment: I think he's asking how to find whether a variable is on register or stack. Does this page really work for it?

Comment: @ahmet: but he also asked us to "list the switch that I need to use with gcc" and `-S` is the switch he needs. He can then examine the assembler files that are generated to see exactly where variables are stored.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at the generated assembly, but there's no way to programmatically determine this from within your program. Generally be aware that GCC ignores the `register` keyword except to issue errors if you try to take the address of a `register`-storage variable, and when used in common with GCC-specific extensions to force a variable into a particular register for use in conjunction with inline asm. No idea what MSVC does.